# I made a website using WordPress, but the server is ColdFusion, how can I make it work?

Tags: uploads, import

I made a website using Wordpress, and when it came time to turn it live, I was told the site server uses Coldfusion. I don't know anything about it but they claim it wouldn't work. Is there anything I can do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Cold Fusion is a web server that processes CFM files along with HTML files. CFM is a web server 'language' similar to the PHP language.  A 'Cold Fusion Server' is built to process the CFM files (which can contain CSS, HTML, and Cold Fusion language directives). So, by default, an index.cfm file will be processed by the Cold Fusion language processor just like an index.php file is processed by the PHP language processor.

When you create a "Cold Fusion" server, you first create a Apache or IIS server instance, then install Cold Fusion on top of that. So to add the ability to process PHP files, you need to install PHP on the same server. Once PHP is installed, WordPress PHP files will be properly processed.

So you can run PHP code on a server that is configured as a Cold Fusion Server. You just need to add the PHP processor to the server. Lots of googles/bings/ducks on how to do that.

That doesn't mean that you can run PHP code on a CFM code page or vice-versa. They are separate 'processes'. (Well, not easily. You might be able to use the Cold Fusion CFHTTP function to call a PHP page.) A CFM page with CFM code will be processed by the Cold Fusion service. A PHP page with PHP code will be processed by the PHP service. But you can't put PHP code in a CFM file (or vice versa) and expect the mixed code to run properly.

But with the PHP service installed, PHP code (index.php, etc) will be processed by the PHP service. CFM code (index.cfm) will be processed by the CFM service.

So your web guy is correct - sort of. Until you install the PHP service on the server, PHP code (and WordPress) will not run. But the PHP code will run if you install the pHP service on the server.

Comment: With 20 years of experience, I thought I have seen it all. But I never stumbled upon Coldfusion before. Or I don't remember. Nice explanation, especially as the Wikipedia page about CF is more of a sales pitch than anything else.

Comment: @kaiser - Did a lot of Cold Fusion back in the 90's (1990, you whippersnapper). Enjoyed working with and DBase. (Yes, I am old.)  :)  Thanks.

Comment: I [added a tag for it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coldfusion). Maybe you find the time to add one or two sentences to it, so search results are improved with the major engines. Thanks!